# Ruby AMQP under Thin HTTP server

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, thin

I'm running a simple thin server, that publish some messages to different queues, the code looks like :

```
require "rubygems"
require "thin"
require "amqp"
require 'msgpack'

app = Proc.new do |env|

 params  = Rack::Request.new(env).params

 command = params['command'].strip rescue "no command"
 number  = params['number'].strip  rescue "no number"

 p command
 p number

AMQP.start do
  if command =~ /\A(create|c|r|register)\z/i
    MQ.queue("create").publish(number)
  elsif m = (/\A(Answer|a)\s?(\d+|\d+-\d+)\z/i.match(command))
    MQ.queue("answers").publish({:number => number,:answer => "answer" }.to_msgpack )
  end
end

 [200, {'Content-Type' => "text/plain"} , command ]

end

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => 4001)
```

Now when I run the server, and do something like http://0.0.0.0:4001/command=r&number=123123123
I'm always getting duplicate outputs, something like :

"no command"
"no number"
"no command"
"no number"

The first thing is why I'm getting like duplicate requests ? is it something has to do with the browser ? since when I use curl I'm not having the same behavior , and the second thing why I can't get the params ?

Any tips about the best implementation for such a server would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second request comes from the browser looking for the `favicon.ico`. You can inspect the requests by adding the following code in your handler:

```
 params  = Rack::Request.new(env).params
 p env # add this line to see the request in your console window
```

Alternatively you could use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/):

```
require "rubygems"
require "amqp"
require "msgpack"
require "sinatra"

get '/:command/:number' do
    command = params['command'].strip rescue "no command"
    number  = params['number'].strip  rescue "no number"
    p command
    p number
    AMQP.start do
        if command =~ /\A(create|c|r|register)\z/i
            MQ.queue("create").publish(number)
        elsif m = (/\A(Answer|a)\s?(\d+|\d+-\d+)\z/i.match(command))
            MQ.queue("answers").publish({:number => number,:answer => "answer" }.to_msgpack )
        nd
    end
    return command
end
```

and then run `ruby the_server.rb` at the command line to start the http server.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Matt. you seems to be right , is there any way to eliminate this behavior ? and is there any example of using Thin with AMQP , the best optimized way to use it , anyways as for the output for p env : https://gist.github.com/78208470bfffbef400fe

Comment: Just a side note: What you were using is actually `rack`, an abstraction-layer/middleware for running web apps on diffrent web servers, and `thin` is the actual webserver running your rack app. You might have more success googling for "rack amqp". Also you should take a look at one of the higher-level AMQP gems like Bunny: https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny. Hope that helps.